# Differences in SQL syntax between SQL Server 2005 and ADO.Net?

Tags: .net, sql-server-2005, ado.net

I was wondering if there was a compilation of any known differences in accepted SQL syntax structure between running a query directly in SQL Management Studio and creating a sql query as a string in a .net application and sending it through a SQLCommand and Connection? I was going to ask about a specific issue I was having with one particular query but its turning out I am having multiple issues with multiple queries. I am basically taking a set of queries written by someone else and injecting them into .Net web parts I am implementing, but I am finding that I need to tweak most of the queries (ie. Table1.Column1 doesn't work, just Column1 works fine)

I was wondering if the issues I am encountering are known differences between the two environments or if the problem lies within database/schema/query structure issues?

EDIT WITH EXAMPLE:

The following 4 queries all work in SQL Management Studio but not passed into a SQL Connection in a .net web part... By failing to work, I mean the web part will not load in the asp page (it is actually a SharePoint page) and I am told by SharePoint it is causing a problem. I'm not sure of the correct sharepoint logs to look at as well...(PLEASE NOTE I am aware that these queries make no sense, such as the pointlessness of the FROM clause, but they are debug queries I was toying with to try and pinpoint the issues)

The 5th query works fine in both SQL Management Studio and in a .Net web part, but it is the opposite logic of what I wanted..

```
//-----------------------------------------------

    SELECT DISTINCT 
            '2011' AS Yr, '01' AS PerNbr, 1 AS Amount 
             FROM Submissions AS s INNER JOIN 
            JurisdictionalData  AS j ON re_KeyTbl = Keytbl AND s.jurisdiction <> REPLACE(j.JurisdictionTxt, 'Jurisdiction', '')

//-----------------------------------------------

SELECT DISTINCT 
        '2011' AS Yr, '01' AS PerNbr, 1 AS Amount 
         FROM Submissions AS s INNER JOIN 
        JurisdictionalData  AS j ON j.re_KeyTbl = s.Keytbl AND s.jurisdiction NOT IN (REPLACE(j.JurisdictionTxt, 'Jurisdiction', ''))

//-----------------------------------------------

SELECT DISTINCT 
        '2011' AS Yr, '01' AS PerNbr, 1 AS Amount 
         FROM Submissions AS s INNER JOIN 
        JurisdictionalData  AS j ON j.re_KeyTbl = s.Keytbl AND s.jurisdiction NOT IN (j.JurisdictionTxt)

//-----------------------------------------------

SELECT DISTINCT 
        '2011' AS Yr, '01' AS PerNbr, 1 AS Amount 
         FROM Submissions AS s INNER JOIN 
        JurisdictionalData  AS j ON j.re_KeyTbl = s.Keytbl AND s.jurisdiction <> j.JurisdictionTxt

//-----------------------------------------------
SELECT DISTINCT 
        '2011' AS Yr, '01' AS PerNbr, 1 AS Amount 
         FROM Submissions AS s INNER JOIN 
        JurisdictionalData  AS j ON j.re_KeyTbl = s.Keytbl AND s.jurisdiction = j.JurisdictionTxt
```

C# code (pretty standard stuff):

class members:

```
//sql db connection string
private string _cnString =
"Server=_server;" +
"Database=_db;" +
"User ID=_user;" +
"Password=_password;" +
"Trusted_Connection=False";

//sql query
    private string query = "SELECT DISTINCT " +
    "'2011' AS Yr, '01' AS PerNbr, 1 AS Amount " + 
     "Submissions AS s INNER JOIN " +
    "JurisdictionalData  AS j ON j.re_KeyTbl = s.Keytbl AND s.jurisdiction = j.JurisdictionTxt ";
```

in my CreateChildControls function:

```
 SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(_cnString);
 //run SQL query and store results in a dataset
        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConn);
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adp.Fill(ds);
```

Comment: There is no difference. Please post the specific example that leads you to believe there is a difference.

Comment: Please add some examples, I have not found any differences in what they accept.

Comment: Very simple queries work fine, but when I pull in any number of SQL functions, they seem to cause issues.

Comment: Post the .NET code that's running the query please, and the actual error message you're receiving, if any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly, the problem is that you don't know how to find the SharePoint logs which would help you solve the problem. So, try to eliminate SharePoint.

Extract the portion of your web part which does the database I/O into separate classes. Call those classes from a normal ASP.NET application. See if you can make it fail the same way.

If not, then try wrapping your ADO.NET code in a try/catch block, and in the catch, try to create an event log entry. See the System.Diagnostics namespace for this.

Finally, maybe you should ask where the error logs would be. Maybe the information is already out there. Maybe you should deploy to a test SharePoint that you have more control over?

Comment: Yea you're pretty much right the SharePoint aspect is a big missing piece when debugging my issues. Will work on your suggestions and re-post if I have any useful breakthroughs/info

Comment: @Alex: WSS 3.0/MOSS 2007? I hear 2010 is a better debug experience so you must be using the older one.

Comment: yup, WSS 3.0/MOSS 2007 is my environment

Comment: @Alex: then, BTW, your exceptions may all be in the event log as warnings with the "ASP.NET" event source. Ask Operations to take a look for you, after you reproduce the problem.

Comment: D'oh! So this was an issue of SQLCommand Timeout and nothing to do with SQL (like you all said). In lieu of my SP admin, I whipped up an asp page and plugged in my web part, which broke on a Timeout expired error for DataAdapter fill. Set the sqlcommand timeout to 0 and it works fine now. (The queries I'm working on return a pretty large dataset, looks like I have to figure out some optimizations). Thanks all for the help, giving this answer credit for pointing out something I should have known on my own...what a waste of a morning!

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no difference.

SQL Server will parse and execute the SQL strings the same way.

Is there something specific you have in mind?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking directly to a SqlCommand (rather than an abstraction like a data-adapter) it should be identical - it is just TSQL sent to te server. The only differences may be the SET options in effect, perhaps the **account** you are using, the default schema etc